# How to ensure different message in sns topic invokes different lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have a lambda fuction which is subscribed to sns topic. The lambda function sends some message to slack channel with the information passed from sns topic for example { fruit = apple}. Value of apple is posted on slack

Now I am experiencing a problem where multiple messages lets say total 3 messages  are sent to sns topic with different values of fruit. The information in lambda is overwritten by the value of latest message in sns topic. ( i.e 3rd message) in other words the values of fruit of the 1st message or 2nd message is not posted on slack.

So how do I make sure that multiple lambda are invoked for multiple messages in the sns topic like 1 message per 1 lambda invocation from a single sns topic. Right now it's like for all the messages single lambda is invoked.

Comment: This looks like a config error or a logic error without knowing any details on the code and the config hard to tell.

Comment: I recommend you add a debugging line to `print(event)` and see what is _actually_ passed to the function. If you are still having problems, please Edit your question to show us the contents of the `event` and also show us your code that is reading the contents of the `event`.

Answer (score 0):

When the AWS Lambda function is invoked by Amazon SNS, it is possible that **multiple messages are being passed** to the Lambda function.

The Lambda function should **loop through the records** like this:

```py
def handler(event, context):
  for record in event['Records']:
    # Do something with record
```

Alternatively, you can **force the Lambda function to only receive one message** by setting the **Batch Size to `1`**. This can be configured on the Trigger in the Lambda function.

Comment: Hi @John, I got your point but this is normally the case when we are using Event Source Mapping, here this is asynchronous invocation. Second thing, I read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33692863/1273882), and [this](https://aws.amazon.com/sns/faqs/#:~:text=Q%3A%20Will%20a%20notification%20contain%20more%20than%20one%20message%3F), both says this array will not have more than one item. Can you please help me understand.

Comment: Best thing is to log the contents of `event` to CloudWatch Logs, with something like `print(event)` (will vary depending on your chosen language). Then, check what the logs contain. You can access the logs via the **Monitoring** tab in the Lambda function, and hit "View in CloudWatch Logs".